# Inconsistent NuGet package and assembly versions

Tags: .net, nuget, version, clr

The NuGet package `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt` , version `4.0.2.206221351`, found [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt/4.0.2.206221351) contains an assembly `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.dll` that has version `4.0.20622.1351`, different from version of the NuGet package.

Why this is not a huge problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NuGet package version numbers are not related to assembly version numbers. They can be different, and must be different from now on, as the package number follow Semantic Versioning.