# SqlClientFactory.CreateCommandBuilder returns null

Tags: ado.net, .net-core

I'm porting a full-framework project to target .NET Core 2.0. It has a call to

```
var builder = SqlClientFactory.Instance.CreateCommandBuilder();
...
```

So I've created a new .NET Core project and added a reference to `System.Data.SqlClient` 4.4.0. Unfortunately it seems that `DbProviderFactory.CreateCommandBuilder` has not been overriden, so that the call to `CreateCommandBuilder` always returns `null`.

I've tried to check if this API was officially available, and [on the first sight](https://apisof.net/catalog/System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientFactory.CreateCommandBuilder()) it seemed so. Because that page says:

- Platform: .NET Core
- Version: 2.0
- Assembly: System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.3.1.0, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a

and I'm using `System.Data.SqlClient` **4.4.0** which is higher than 4.3.1.

However, to my next surprise I've found out that  `typeof(SqlClientFactory).Assembly` said `System.Data.SqlClient` **4.2.0.**. I had to learn that [assembly and package versions are allowed to be inconsistent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41581576/331281). I'm unsure then, why https://apisof.net is telling me Core 2.0. It seems it cannot be trusted.

So, I went to [the .NET API Browser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/?view=netcore-2.0&term=CreateCommandBuilder) who correctly does not list `CreateCommandBuilder` for `SqlClientFactory`.

My question is, how can I get the before-mentioned `System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.3.1` assembly? The [4.4 nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SqlClient/4.4.0) I'm using seems to be the latest one by the time of writing.

The only thing I can think of is to compile my own `corefx` checkout in order to get a working `CreateCommandBuilder`. Or start copying bits and pieces like the `SqlCommandBuilder`. But I don't know if that is a good idea.

Comment: Those classes are used mainly by the client itself to work with datasets, which have been replaced by ORMs and micro ORMs. .NET Core didn't even have Datasets until 2.0. What does this code do? Perhaps you should add the [Compatibility Pack](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/11/16/announcing-the-windows-compatibility-pack-for-net-core/) or *replace* the code with EF Core or Dapper. Such classes are used for mapping and generating SQL statements, something included in every ORM

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: yes, it's related to DataSets but I can't rip those out since in this app there's data-binding in WinForms going on etc. But I didn't know about that Compatibility Pack. Thanks a lot! Checking it out now...

Comment: You tagged this question as *.NET Core*. How are you going to build a WinForms application there? Besides, WinForms does *NOT* require Datasets for data binding. Controls can bind to any class, although it isn't as clean as with WPF

Comment: Are you trying to create a *.NET Standard* library perhaps? Then you *can't* use classes that don't exist in your target.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: yes, it's a class lib targeting .NET Standard 2.0 that I'm actually building. But that doesn't matter. You can build a Core 2.0 console app and still CreateCommandBuilder doesn't work. And of course, I don't need DataSets in order to data-bind. But I already have a WinForms app that works and I'm porting just parts to .NET Core.

Comment: @Dejan .NET Standard class libraries are build against the .NET Standard. and System.Data.SqlClient isn't part of the standard. If you take a look at the Dependencies section of the NuGet package for it (https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SqlClient/) you'll see that it requires the Windows32 Registry which will never be part of .NET Standard as it a Windows API